# Sympy: How to find longest expression that all N expressions have in common

Tags: python, sympy, boolean-logic

I have N expressions in Sympy and I need to find the longest expression that all N expressions have in common (like the longest expression is in/contained in all that N expressions)

```
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy.logic.boolalg import And, Not, Or
a = Symbol("a")
b = Symbol("b")

expr0 = And(And(a, b), c)
expr1 = Not(And(a, b))
expr2 = Or(Not(a), Not(b))
#?? now how to find that all expressions contains And(a,b) ?
```

Why I need it? I have some expressions and I need to build If-then-else block for them:

```
expr0 causes operation Op0
expr1 causes operation Op1
expr2 causes operation Op2

and the result should be:
And(a,b) is longest expression which all of expr have in common
so I will be able to build if then else block like this

If (And(a, b)) {
    if(c)
        Op0;
}else{
    op1;
    op2;
}
```

So this is why i need to find the longest expression that all N expressions have in common.
To optimalize this If-then-else blocks.

Comment: Do you need to check if `expr0` is contained in `expr1`? Or do you need to check if `expr1==expr2`? Maybe both? It's rather unclear what you need. Provide a few examples.

Comment: I need to find largest expression which is subset of expressions which I have.

Comment: As I already said, provide an example that demonstrates your needs.

Comment: Do you need to find the largest common subexpression of two expressions? Concerning logic, have you tried simplify_logic( ) to better compare logical expressions?

Comment: Yes but simplify_logic( ) and then manual searching in expression tree does not work in all cases for example: `simplify_logic(expr1 ) = Or(Not(a), Not(b))` and then I am not able to find that expr0 and expr1 has And(a,b) in common

Answer (score 3):

SymPy objects have the *.has( ... )* method:

```
>>> expr1.has(expr0)
True

>>> expr2.has(expr0)
False
```

Regarding the rest of Python (i.e. not SymPy), you should better define what you mean by shared expression. Logical operations are usually supposed to return a value, not to build an expression.

**EDIT**

OK, from the discussion I understand that you want to look for a common subexpression between two expressions (so, not testing whether a subexpression is a common one).

Furthermore, you'd like to logically match equivalent expressions, that is, expressions that look differently but are logically equivalent should be matched as equivalent. This makes everything a bit more complicated, but I propose you an easy solution.

SymPy has the *satisfiable( )* function, which finds solutions to logical expressions. If you pass the parameter *all_models=True*, this function will return all solutions that satisfy that logical condition:

```
In [5]: list(satisfiable(expr2, all_models=True))
Out[5]: [{b: False, a: False}, {b: False, a: True}, {b: True, a: False}]
```

The function *preorder_traversal* allows us to visit the whole expression tree (that is, easily create a for-loop to visit all subexpressions). So we can construct a double for-loop to perform the search on the subexpressions of *expr1*, check their satisfiability, perform a second for loop on the other expression (*expr2* in this example), and compare the satisfiabilities of the two subexpressions:

```
for e1 in preorder_traversal(expr1):
    s1 = list(satisfiable(e1 ,all_models =True ))
    for e2 in preorder_traversal (expr2):
        s2 = list (satisfiable (e2 ,all_models =True ))
        if s1 == s2:
            print("Logically equiv subexpr found: ", e1, " and ", e2)
```

If you put here your *expr1* and *expr2*, you'll get:

```
('Logically equiv subexpr found: ', Not(And(a, b)), ' and ', Or(Not(a), Not(b)))
('Logically equiv subexpr found: ', b, ' and ', b)
('Logically equiv subexpr found: ', a, ' and ', a)
```

I think you can easily adapt this code to your needs.

**EDIT 2**

To handle cases in which the tree splits into more than two subexpressions (that is, cases like *And(a, b, c, d)* or *Xor(a, b, c, d, e)*), you could generate subsets like this (**code is not tested this time**):

```
# get a function to generate all subsets of a tuple,
# let's say `subsets( )`

for e1 in preorder_traversal(expr1):
    for es1 in subsets(e1.args):
        s1 = list(satisfiable(e1.func(*es1), all_models=True))
        # NOW do the same with the `e2` for-loop,
        # then compare `s1` and `s2` as usual.
```

This code would appear like a series of 4 nested for-loops, but it can be rearranged defining some helper functions, to make it look nicer.

It can be further generalized to compare more than two expressions, again better reorganize the code a bit first.

**EDIT 3**

I thought a bit overnight, I think you can further improve this algorithm by sifting the first expression only with *satisfiable( )*, once you get the boolean solutions for your symbols, just replace them in the other expressions to see which part are compatible.

Comment: Problem is that in Sympy And,Or,Xor .. etc.. can have more than two arguments it means for `And(a,b,c) and And(a,b) `  this will not work, but thank you nearly solved the issue, but still solution is ultimate performance hit.